# Input 24v Button with esp32 (or esp8266) with esphome

Tags: esp32, home-assistant

[image]

I'm trying to create a panel for my pool.

I've searched for electronic valves, LEDs (for valves status) and buttons (for run an automation with HomeAssistant)
For the valves and LEDs I think that theorically it will work based on the info on internet.

But for the button is a different story.
I've searched for a method to send a signal to esp32 when the 24v circuit of a button is closed (the button is pressed), but I can't find any way.

If I'm right, a relay opens/closes a circuit when it receives a signal from esp32. Is there any way to do the opposite - send a signal to esp32 when the 24v circuit is closed (button is pressed)?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... also, a wiring diagram would go a long way towards explaining what you are trying to do

Comment: In the photo there are 3 buttons that close a 24v circuit when pressed (the buttons have a led status that turn on when pressed)
I need to know what device I need to receive a signal to a GPIO pin on an esp32 when the circuit is closed.

Comment: 24 V AC or 24 V DC? ... the circuit shows switches that short out the power supply when closed ... where are the status lights in the circuit?

Comment: 24 DC.
Yes, the buttons have led that turns ON when pressed.
This are the buttons (model 24v, momentary, 4 pin) https://es.aliexpress.com/item/33055445497.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.5915194df3928y&gatewayAdapt=glo2esp

Comment: I asked you where the lights are in the circuit diagram ... the physical location of the status lights is irrelevant

Comment: there are many ways to detect the 24 Vdc ... all are documented on the web ... don't search for `method to send a signal to esp32 when the 24v circuit of a button is closed` .... search for words `microcontroller detect 24 V`

Comment: **caution !!!** ... make sure that the 24 Vdc is isolated from power line ... a  24 Vdc circuit could easily be connected to 200 V and 224 V